# PHP Foreach() invalid argument

Tags: php

I'm receiving the fooling error below but not sure why. the $_Post all have data.

**error:** Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/soc/process_member.php on line 19

```
    $valid = true; 
    foreach($_POST['add'] && $_POST['cpl'] as $value) { 
        if(!isset($value)) { 
            $valid = false;
        } 
    }
    if(!$valid) { 
        $err .= 'please fill in all fields';
        $en['reg_error'] = '<div class=err style="color: #FF0000;"><b>'._error.': '.$err.'</b></div><br>';
        load_template('modules/members/templates/s_reg.tpl');   
    }
```

Comment: In PHP, result of `&&` operation is boolean.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your && operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is a [merged](http://php.net/array_merge) array:

```
foreach(array_merge($_POST['add'], $_POST['cpl']) as $value) {
  // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You should read more about PHP. There are two syntaxes for "foreach":

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

This is totally wrong:

```
foreach($_POST['add'] && $_POST['cpl'] as $value) {
```

Let me give you an example:

```
<?php
foreach (array(1, 2, 3, 4) as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
?>
```

For more info, check the official PHP Documentation regarding foreach: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: you shouldn't use: $_POST['add'] && $_POST['cpl']

Answer (score 1):

First, in PHP, result of `&&` operation is always boolean (i.e., `true` or `false`) - and you cannot supply it into `foreach` (and why you may wish to?), hence the error.

Second, even if it were possible, it'd still make little sense to use `isset` here: if either `$_POST['add']` or `$_POST['cpl']` is indeed unset, the notice *is* raised.

So, you can either just rewrite the first section of your code like this:

```
$valid = isset($_POST['add']) && isset($_POST['cpl']);
```

... or, taking into account the flexible nature of `isset` construct, just...

```
$valid = isset($_POST['add'], $_POST['cpl']);
```

... because, as said in its' [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only
>   if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right
>   and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

If there's actually a whole big set of args to check and/or you're too lazy to type '$_POST' each time, use `foreach` to go through the array of their *names* (and not the actual values!) instead:

```
$valid = true;
foreach (array('add', 'cpl', 'whatever', 'it', 'takes') as $argName) {
  if (! isset($_POST[$argName])) {
    $valid = false;
    break;
  }
}
```